# Brushless motor control without ESC

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I saw a [video](https://youtu.be/geT94tV-xBM) on the net, titled *"How to Convert Car Alternator To Brushless Motor / No ESC With Mosfet Driver"*.

I understand in principle how an ESC works, but I don't understand how this circuit would. The circuit:

[image]

Can somebody explain how this works in principle? Or in more detail, in plain words, or technical terms?

Roughly I know it's using differences between phases, but I have no idea what those differences are. These questions also come to mind: Does it have a dead point at which it can't start? Is the rotation direction determined or random? Is the efficiency of the circuit worse compared to a normal ESC circuit? In general, what type of circuit is this?

Comment: Any feedback circuit is a challenge to understand!  It looks like it starts with all phases on and when the motor starts turning it sorts itself out. It looks like the phase sequence is fixed, so it should only rotate one way. Depending on the position of the rotor vs pole, a given phase will generate a voltage which turns off the mosfet which causes the next one to turn on and so on. Is it efficient? Probably not - I have no experience with these. Try it and make some measurements. It’s cheap n cheerful! Set expectations low.

Comment: Very cool! Kartman. Can you put it into an answer?

Comment: https://odysee.com/@GreatScott:a/i-followed-a-youtube-electronics-video:9
TLDR; I wouldn't recommend using that circuit.

Comment: Ok, GreatScott has an analysis and experimentation. On some motors, it starts by itself, but not others. It's not efficient. Thanks, @Drew!